# Efeito borrado no fundo do edit text

Tags: android

Como colocar o efeito borrado no fundo do edit text?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_border"
        android:hint="E-mail"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/btn_color"
        android:textColorHighlight="@color/btn_color"
        android:textColorHint="@color/btn_color"
        />
```

Comment: poderia mandar uma imagem para nos dar a ideia doq vc quer exatamente?

Comment: Pronto coloquei a foto